# Removing commas and brackets from this output

Tags: graphics

Being a Mathematica beginner, how can I remove the brackets and the comma's in this output? And, how can I make the rectangles touch?

```
a = Range[0, 10]
g[p_] = Graphics[{Hue[p/50], Rectangle[{p, 0}]}];
g /@ a
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are generating separate `Graphics` objects. Try this instead: `Graphics[{
  {Hue[#/50], Rectangle[{#, 0}]} & /@ Range[0, 10]
  }]`

Comment: To answer the question: change the last line of your code to `Show[g /@ a]`